# How to return records based on time availability in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a SQL query that will return available doctors based on the time availability.

`StartTime, EndTime  TIME(0)`  -- data type

```
INSERT INTO Schedule(PatientId, DoctorId, DayOfWeek,StartTime,EndTime) 
(1,100,'Sunday','8:00 AM','11:00 AM')
INSERT INTO Schedule(PatientId, DoctorId, DayOfWeek,StartTime,EndTime) 
(1,101,'Monday','12:00 PM','03:00 PM')

INSERT INTO Schedule(PatientId, DoctorId, DayOfWeek,StartTime,EndTime) 
(2,100,'Sunday','5:00 PM','7:00 PM')
INSERT INTO Schedule(PatientId, DoctorId, DayOfWeek,StartTime,EndTime) 
(2,101,'Friday','4:00 PM','6:00 PM')
```

In the given table we can store schedules between patient and doctor. I need a SQL query where the query will return DoctorId. And also per week, a doctor can have a total of 40 hours (8 hours/5 days). so if I pass a parameter that I need the doctors who have >= 50% time available out of 40 hours.

**Example:** If I want to get DoctorId (100), he might be busy with any patient on Sunday(2 hrs) and Monday (2 hrs). but his 36 hrs still available for the week. the SQL will return the DoctorId (100)

Comment: So what is your question here? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I still don't see a question in your question, nor attempts or details of why they didn't work, @sebu .

Comment: A doubt I've got is why are you taking this StartDate and EndDate and yes as @Larnu said do provide the query you've tried so far to achieve the required solution.

Comment: @groovy_guy please check my question I edited. removed start date and end date

Comment: @sebu isn't this gonna be difficult if you don't have any date to understand for which week are we calculating the hours for? You should have the date of appointment

Comment: @Larnu i don't know how to design the query for this problem, i edited my question

Comment: @groovy_guy you can try just for 7 days (week) Sunday to Saturday.

Comment: Please describe a specific query you'll be making against this data, and for that query give the exact results you'd expect *(based on the sample data in your question)*.  For example; Do you want to list all doctors who's total hours are less than 20hrs *(which would return two rows; doctor id's 1 and 2)*?  Or do you want to to know if a specific doctor has availability at a specific time?  Perhaps read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MatBailie thanks, I need the doctors who have greater than 20 hrs availability.

Comment: Please add the datatypes for your columns.

Comment: @MatBailie StartTime, EndTime  TIME(0) -- data type

Comment: Please edit your question to include everything in your comments, then delete those comments.  A question should be complete and not require trawling through all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the `DATEDIFF(second, StartTime, EndTime)` you will get how many seconds that schedule entry covers.

So, if you sum that value up across all of a doctor's rows, you can see how many seconds they're busy for in total.

Then, if you want to see doctors who have more than 50% of their time free, you just look for doctors who have less than 20hrs of scheduled appointments *(where `20 hrs` == `20 * 60 * 60 seconds`)*...

```
SELECT
  DoctorId,
  SUM(DATEDIFF(second, StartTime, EndTime)) / (60.0 * 60.0)   AS hrs_busy
FROM
  Schedule
GROUP BY
  DoctorId
HAVING
  SUM(DATEDIFF(second, StartTime, EndTime)) <= (20 * 60 * 60)
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5bd2fc110d7039acadcb280323df9d77